# Grails URL mappings

Tags: grails, url-rewriting, seo

In my Grails app I have a couple of domain classes, say `Author` and `Book`. I'm using the default URL mappings:

```
static mappings = {
  "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
    constraints {
      // apply constraints here
    }
  }
}
```

So the relative URL to show the book with id 2 is `/book/show/2` or for the author with id 5 it's `/author/show/5`. Both the `Author` and `Book` classes have a unique `name` property.

I would prefer the URLs to show an author or book use the name rather than the database ID to identify the book/author, e.g. `/author/show/shakespeare` and `/book/show/ulysses`. Is this achievable without changing the domain classes such that the name field is the id (primary key)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pass strings (e.g. "shakespeare") as `params.id` and then instead of doing a:

```
Author.get(params.id)
```

in your controller method, do:

```
Author.findByName(params.id)
```

As far as I know, the `id` parameter (when used with URLs) doesn't *have* to be a `long`.

Comment: Just did a quick test with this and it seemed to work. Went to `http://example.com:8080/myapp/books/show/Book1` and saw it render out my bootstrapped book named "Book1". Admittedly, this involves a fair amount of work in your controllers to change everywhere.

Comment: Changing the controllers is the easy part - I probably only need to modify (one line in) a single action for each domain class. The more difficult part is tracking down all the places where that action is called and changing it to send the name instead of ID. Anyway, there doesn't seem to be an alternative, so you win the coveted check mark. Hearty congratulations, and thank you.